# QGIS Masking part of objects at other layer

Tags: qgis, symbology, masking

i'm using qgis 3.14. I have situation like in the screen below: [image]

I'd like to hide that part of river which is under the bridge. So the result would be like:
[image]

I'd like to avoid editing original data set. Maybe it's possible by symbolization or masking, if not please tell the solution with editing data.

Comment: If your terrain colour is always the same, simply add a wide strip of terrain colour to the bridge and place it below the road.

Comment: this is my current solution, but terrain isn't always the same. thats the main problem